# Use of Index funtion in VBA returning run-time error message

Tags: vba, excel, indexing

I can't figure out why my cog a run-time is returning a run-time error message

> Unable to get index property for worksheet function.

Below is my code,

```
 Function Distance() As Integer

 Distance = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(Workbooks("Practice 1.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("I11:P18"), Range("K12"))

 End Function
```

Comment: Fix the formatting and typos? The problem is not clear.

Comment: since you're passing Index function a two dim array as the first parameter, you're missing the column parameter as the last one

Comment: how bout `function Distance() as variant` ?

Answer (score 0):

The index function needs range, row and column - thus three parameters. In your case you only give two. If you start a new empty application, and you write

```
?Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(Range("A1:C10"), Range("D1"),Range("D2")).address
```

in the immediate window, you would get `$A$2:$C$2`, in case that you write *2* in D2 and *1* in E1.

Or with your code something like this:

```
 Function Distance() As Integer

 Distance = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(Workbooks("Practice 1.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("I11:P18"), Range("K12"),1)

 End Function
```